# gridview cells in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

While back I asked a question on adding clients to a listview, but I am wanting to transition it to gridview similar to this picture. They use textview and tablelayout, but it doesn't have to be that whatever is easier. http://sdroid.blogspot.com/2011/01/fixed-header-in-tablelayout.html would using textview/tablelayout, or is there better way of doing that?
I attempted to do it but it overlapped my header.. I forgot to save the code to show to see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you would like a fixed header displayed at the top of your screen. Below that, you would like a (scrollable?) gridview. Is this correct?

If so, than this is easy to accomplish. Use the FragmentActivity class (instead of the Activity class). Implement two fragments on your main page. An upper fragment will contain the header. The lower fragment will contain your gridview. They can both be displayed at the same time.

Comment: Hey ksoren thanks for the answer. At the moment I am using TableLayout with TextView, Would performance be better if I used fragmentactivity class? Here is another question that is little weird, but should I make a separate class to customize my gui? Instead of doing it on my main class?

Comment: I think a TextView with TableLayout is fine if it is producing the results that you want. Regarding your second question: No, don't make a separate class to customize your gui. Instead, just make a CustomizeGui method in your main class that you call from the onCreate or other similar location inside of your main class.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I decided to go with expandable listview.